# how to combine PHP arrays from form entries

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a form that allows the user to select multiple "keys" and then dynamically add any amount of values after. I need to combine them tied to each "key" to insert as rows in CSV.
example data from form submit:

```
$locations = array(loc1,loc2,loc3,loc4)
$input1 = array(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)
$input2 = array(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5)
$input3 = array(C1,C2,C3,C4,C5)
```

Output as:

```
$OutToCVS = array(loc1,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)
$OutToCVS = array(loc1,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5)
$OutToCVS = array(loc1,C1,C2,C3,C4,C5)
$OutToCVS = array(loc2,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)
$OutToCVS = array(loc2,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5)
$OutToCVS = array(loc2,C1,C2,C3,C4,C5)
$OutToCVS = array(loc3,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)
$OutToCVS = array(loc3,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5)
$OutToCVS = array(loc3,C1,C2,C3,C4,C5)
$OutToCVS = array(loc4,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)
$OutToCVS = array(loc4,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5)
$OutToCVS = array(loc4,C1,C2,C3,C4,C5)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Iterate over arrays and create result data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example code to start with:

```
foreach ($locations as $loc) {
    $OutToCVS[] = array_merge([$loc], $input1);
    $OutToCVS[] = array_merge([$loc], $input2);
    $OutToCVS[] = array_merge([$loc], $input3);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/OPVG3).

Comment: Ok, this get me to where I can get an output like: Array ([0] => Array ( [0]=> loc1 [1] =>$input1 [2] =>input2)  [1]=> loc2 [1] =>$input1 [2] =>input2)

Comment: I need it to give a round for each input with location repeated. Does this make sense?

Comment: Checking against it now. Just tried again, and not getting the correct results. I will update accordingly. Thank you.